# Cuando actualizo la página, la respuesta de la API es undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Cuando intento acceder a un elemento de la api en princpio puedo, pero una vez actualizo la página me da error.
[image: Objeto que recibo]
Una vez he recibido el objeto y intento entrar en el, si no actualizo la página todo funciona, pero en el momento que actualizo me da el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState({});
  const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Ccardano%2Cpolkadot%2Cdogecoin%2Clitecoin%2Cchainlink%2Ctezos&vs_currencies=usd';

  const getApi = async () => {
      const request = await fetch (url);
      const response = await request.json();
     setCoins(response);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      getApi();
  },[])

    console.log(coins.bitcoin.usd)
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pareciera ser un error de asincronía, cuando refrescas tu página tienes por defecto coins inicializado en `{}` tal y como lo defines en tu `setState` y esto significa que no puedes acceder `coins.bitocins.usd` porque estas propiedades no existen en un objeto vacío. Para que entiendas mejor el problema voy a editar tu código de manera en que observes cómo se hace el `console.log` antes de que lleguen los datos y por lo tanto no se puede acceder los elementos que quieres.

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState({});
  const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Ccardano%2Cpolkadot%2Cdogecoin%2Clitecoin%2Cchainlink%2Ctezos&vs_currencies=usd';

  const getApi = async () => {
      const request = await fetch (url);
      const response = await request.json();
      console.log("Hasta ahorita llegan los datos!");
     setCoins(response);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      getApi();
  },[])

  console.log(`Trantado de mostrar los datos de coins.bitcoin.usd: ${coins.bitcoin.usd}`)
```

Generalmente lo que hacemos es que indicamos que se están obteniendo los datos por medio de la interfaz:

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState({});
  const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Ccardano%2Cpolkadot%2Cdogecoin%2Clitecoin%2Cchainlink%2Ctezos&vs_currencies=usd';

  const getApi = async () => {
      const request = await fetch (url);
      const response = await request.json();
      console.log("Hasta ahorita llegan los datos!");
     setCoins(response);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      getApi();
  },[])

 return(
     <div>{coins==={} ? "Espere, obteniendo datos" : `coins.bitcoin.us:${coins.bitcoin.us}`}</div>
 );
```

En este caso mientras se estén obteniendo los datos se va a renderizar el objeto como un texto que dice *Espere, obteniendo datos* y una vez que estos datos se obtengan se muestra el resultado. Hay muchas maneras de hacer esto, esto es un ejemplo sencillo adaptado a tu código que te permita entender que la asincronía es inevitable y la manera de solucionar estos problemas es por medio de hacerle saber al usuario que tiene que esperar.

Comment: Vale, comprendo.

Comment: Debería entonces inicializar el state de alguna forma para que al principio la respuesta no fuese undefined no? Como sería?

Comment: Generalmente lo que se hace es que en donde lo vas a mostrar al usuario los datos chequeas por el valor de inicialización y le avisas al usuario que todavía no se tienen los datos a disposición, que espere. Te hago un ejemplo  editando la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Te da error porque hasta que no ha obtenido la respuesta de la API, la primera vez que renderiza cuando intenta hacer el `console.log`, `coins` es un objeto vacío, por lo que cuando intenta acceder a `coins.bitcoin.usd` da error ya que `coins.bitcoin` ya es `undefined`.

Deberías controlar de algún modo que `coins` tiene valor antes de acceder a sus subniveles.

Comment: Como podría entonces inicializar el objeto al principio hasta que me llegase el request?

Comment: podrías por ejemplo inicializarlo a null, y el console.log hacerlo así coins && console.log(coins.bitcoin.usd) de modo que solo lo hará cuando coins tenga valor